# php filter form output /"Other" optional textbox

Tags: php, forms, output, textfield, hidden

I need to know how to display the users "other" answer that they type in... and NOT display the "other" value that is assigned to the radio button.

Basically, in the list of answers, the last one is "Other". When they select it, a hidden text field appears so they can type in their answer.

With PHP, can you say something like "if other is selected, only show answer inputted and not the value of Other"?

Can PHP check against the answers and display the right one?

Sorry, don't know how to explain or ask my question. I couldn't get my form to work on jsfiddle either.

Thanks,
Tracy

Comment: I think you should use JavaScript for this problem

Comment: yep as north wind said you have to do it in javascript, php can't do it except if you already have the value before send the page

Comment: Please show what you've tried - it's unclear if you mean to toggle form elements, process user output, or both.

Comment: I have not tried anything, but finally managed to set it up as a fiddle, but it's very bare basics. https://jsfiddle.net/flipflopmedia/odajucdn/ And thank you.. perhaps that's why I was not finding any help in my php search... I look to finding a javascript example to help.

Comment: So I am looking into this javascript, but am already referencing a php file through the action attribute on the form tag... onsubmit opens a new window for those php results. So how/where do I call the javascript file that's customizing my form results? I added it to the "onsubmit" attribute, that didn't work. I put the script directly in the php document (top and bottom of page), that didn't work. ???